# ggplot2: How to plot barplot, where bars signify percentage and are colored according to percentage value?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to make a specific type of barplot and I need to use ggplot2 - sad thing is I have little knowledge of this package - I started learning about it today.

I have data frame like this:

```
name <- letters[1:10]
percentage <- c(0.74, 0.856, 0.14, 0.97, 0, 0.99, 0.862, 0.5, 0.234, 0.76)
df <- data.frame(name = name, percentage = percentage)

       name percentage
1     a      0.740
2     b      0.856
3     c      0.140
4     d      0.970
5     e      0.000
6     f      0.990
7     g      0.862
8     h      0.500
9     i      0.234
10    j      0.760
```

On the y axis should be names, on the x axis should be percentages. For each name horizontal bar should be plotted. Bar should be divided into two sections:

- first with length equal to percentage, colored according to percentage value : green if percentage > 0.95, orange if percentage > 0.85, red otherwise
- second with length 1 - percentage, colored grey

I made something resembling the specifications with barplot ( but it's ugly, not all the names are visible and there is no second section):

```
barplot(df$percentage , main = "Percentage per letter", 
        horiz = TRUE,    names.arg = df$name, xlim = c(0,1),
        col = ifelse(df$percentage > 0.95, "green", 
        ifelse(df$percentage > .85,'orange','red')))
```

With ggplot2 I managed to achive this:

```
ggplot( data = df, aes( x = name, y = percentage)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  coord_flip() + theme_minimal()
```

Can someone provide me with some hints?

EDIT:

Thanks to help of @lukeA I managed to build very nice looking barplot. Here's my code:

```
# Set colours (nice red, nice orange, nice green)
colours <- c("#D73027", "#FDAE61","#1A9850")

# Transform table:
df <- rbind(
  transform(df, type = 1, fill = cut(percentage, breaks = c(-Inf, 0.85, 0.95, Inf), right = TRUE, labels = colours)),
  transform(df, percentage = 1 - percentage, type = 2, fill = "#EEEEEE")
)

# Name as alphabetically ordered factor (to ensure, that names will be placed in 
# alphabetical order on y axis)
df <- within( df, name <- ordered(name, levels = rev(sort(unique(name)))))

ggplot(data = df, 
       aes( x = name, y = percentage, fill = fill)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", width = 0.75) + 
  scale_fill_identity(guide = "none")  + 
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11, colour = "black" ),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11, colour = "black" ),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(10,10,10,10),"mm")
  )
```

[image: --]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build up on this:

```
dat <- rbind(
  transform(df, fill = cut(percentage, breaks=c(-Inf,.85, .95, Inf), right = T, labels = c("red", "orange", "green"))),
  transform(df, percentage=1-percentage, fill="grey")
)
ggplot( data = dat, aes( x = name, y = percentage, fill = fill)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="stack") + 
  scale_fill_identity(guide="none")+
  coord_flip() + theme_minimal()
```

Comment: use `position="dodge"`if you want bars side by side